# ruby nil confusing me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I've started learning Ruby since  yesterday. Below is my doubt:

```
class MegaGreeter
      attr_accessor :names

      def intialize(names="World!")
        @names = names
      end

      def say_test
        if @names.nil?
          puts "nil test..."
        end
      end  

    end


    megaGreeter = MegaGreeter.new
    megaGreeter.say_test // Here showing ouput as "nil test..."
```

At first I am just `assuming 'nil' almost like 'null' in java`. But my assumption seems wrong in above case.

I dont understand why in above `if @names.nil returning as TRUE`?, since `@names will have a value "World!"` so, how @names considered as null?

I already searched regarding '`nil`', but I really didn't understood clearly about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo. `#intialize` should be `initialize`.

See,

```
class MegaGreeter
  attr_accessor :names

  def initialize(names = "World!")
    @names = names
  end

  def say_test
    if @names.nil?
      puts "nil test..."
    else
      puts "@names is not holding nil"
    end
  end  
end

megaGreeter = MegaGreeter.new
megaGreeter.say_test # => @names is not holding nil
megaGreeter = MegaGreeter.new(nil)
megaGreeter.say_test # => nil test...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot finding out that.. Just a doubt: Can I assume  'nil' in ruby as 'null' in java? Please clear me this

Comment: Nah! Don't confuse Ruby with Java.  _nil_ is a _object_. Here all are _objects_, except _block_. When you will pass a message to an object it will respond if it has the method, otherwise or not. Ruby is _duck typed_.

Comment: In what cases I have to use 'nil' and 'respond_to' , please clear me this.. I already read docs, but didnt understood clearly!

Comment: @user3815806 Please get a book, and go through the topics to understand the Ruby fundamentals.. Docs wouldn't help you that much. This [book](http://www.manning.com/black2/) is enough to get you started,

Comment: Thanks  a lot Bro! I found pdf of it.

Comment: @user3815806 Good! I read the book.. So I knew the quality of it.. read page by page.